# scrollview, buttons events exchange

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview where I added several buttons (dynamically, programmatically). Hence my view is totally covered with buttons. Also there are some labels

However, I observed that the uiscrollview is not scrolling when the drag starts on the button. All labels work fine. But I want this scroll to happen i.e. when drag event occurs in the uibutton, I want it to send this event to its superview (scrollview).

Please note, according to my search, subclassing the scrollview and overrriding the content touches event, or add touch began actions to uibuttons are not helpful.

How do one in general work with this event passing things when objects are added dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You have to subclass the `UIScrollView`, there's no other proper way, but you do not need to mess with the touch events. All you have to do is override this method

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
  return YES;
}
```

And set the `canCancelContentTouches` property of the `UIScrollView` to YES.